# cannot add XAttribute into an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement, xattribute

I want to add an attribute into an element. And I wish the new added attribute to be the first attribute in the element. I used the `AddFirst()`, I got an error : `"An attribute cannot be added to content."` I don't know why?

the following is my codes.

```
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root",
                                new XAttribute("Att1", "content1"),
                                new XAttribute("Att2", "content2")
                            );

xmlTree.AddFirst(new XAttribute("test", "testAttr"));
```

Any other way allows me to add an attribute as a first attribute in the element?

Comment: `AddFirst` is adding a `child` to element, not attribute. And by the way, the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant, meaning you can append the new attribute to the end of the attribute list and XML parser will treat both cases indifferently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your problem. AddFirst can not be use in this case.

```
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root",
                                new XAttribute("Att1", "content1"),
                                new XAttribute("Att2", "content2")
                            );

var attributes = xmlTree.Attributes().ToList();
attributes.Insert(0, new XAttribute("test", "testAttr"));
xmlTree.ReplaceAttributes(attributes);
```